# Не получается запустить .each() функцию

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вопрос заключается в том что не получается заставить работать выборку по условию, конкретно пример кода:

```
<table>
<tr><td style="white-space: nowrap;">Клас хвороб:</td><td><div id="svc_mkxclass">Не визначено</div></td></tr>
<tr><td style="white-space: nowrap;">Kод захворювання:</td><td><div id="svc_mkxkod">Не визначено</div></td></tr>
<tr><td style="white-space: nowrap;">Нозологічна форма:</td><td><div id="svc_mkxdiagn">Не визначено</div></td></tr>
</table>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var SvcCheck = [{"class":"1"},{"kod":"1"},{"diagn":"1"}];
    $( "[id^='svc']" ).each(SvcCheck, function(i, field){
        var name = '#svc_mkx' + field.name;
        var value = parseInt( field.value * 1 );        
        if ( value != 0 ) {
            $( name ).css({ 'color': 'red' });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

для наглядности это же на [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/Mister_X_2k/x45qjew8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы перемешали два вида функции `each` в jQuery, не говоря уже о непонятно откуда взявшихся свойствах `name` и `value`.

```js
$(function() {
  var SvcCheck = [
    { name: "class", value: 1 }, 
    { name: "kod", value: 1 }, 
    { name: "diagn", value: 1 }
  ];
  $.each(SvcCheck, function(i, field) {
    var name = '#svc_mkx' + field.name;
    if (field.value != 0) {
      $(name).css({ 'color': 'red' });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Клас хвороб:</td>
    <td><div id="svc_mkxclass">Не визначено</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Kод захворювання:</td>
    <td><div id="svc_mkxkod">Не визначено</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Нозологічна форма:</td>
    <td><div id="svc_mkxdiagn">Не визначено</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Игорь, огромное спасибо за наставление на путь истинный. Видимо сказалось недостаточное количество знаний и усталость.